# Lagrangian for $\mathcal{N}=4$ SQED in 3D

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, research-level, quantum-electrodynamics, supersymmetry, kaluza-klein

1. What is the Lagrangian for [$3D$ $\mathcal{N}=4$ supersymmetric QED, with $N_f$ hypermultiplets](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=3d+supersymmetric+qed+sqed+hypermultiplet&as_epq=N%3D4)?
2. In particular, which is the form of the Fayet-Iliopulos terms, and the real mass terms?